# How To Get VLC Multiple Playlists With A Single Instance?

Tags: vlc-media-player, playlists, single-instance

**Requirments:**

I need to get VLC to have the ability to:

1. Add many playlists.
2. Deal with each playlist separately.
3. Have the player remember every playlist play position when moving
   between them.

I need these three requirements altogether, without having to open more than one instance of the player.

I thoroughly looked up the Internet with no luck. I know some players can do some of what I need but I need the whole functionality especially number 3.

So,

**How to make VLC a "Real" Multiple Playlists Management player  with a single instance?**

Comment: Short answer?  I just read the docs and it looks like you don't.  I suggest you [get programming](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_Developers_Corner/).  :)  and modify the code to do what you need.  I can tell by your SO profile that you should have these skills.  What a great opportunity to flex them!

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature request for this at
[Restore playlist state when re-opening app](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=155652),
but no solution.

The official VLC position is that bookmarks help save positions.
Read this for example :
[How to Remember Video Playback Position in VLC to Resume Later](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/remember-playback-position-vlc/).

Unfortunately, this doesn't help you with your problem.
You might need to look for another player that has this feature.

Comment: In fact, I am open to the idea of using another media player. I already tried players like MP3 Player, Music Bee, and some others. They have good multi-playlist functionality, but none of them as far as I know supports remembering the play position when moving between these playlists. The problem is that SE won't allow asking about software. I will keep looking as far as I could.